# How to call a function to be able to access the variables passes as an params-JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access 2 variables passed to a function while rendering the data:

js:

```
render: function(){
  var self = this;
  self.publishEvent("render",msg,msg2); //publishEvent is a in-built function in d3 (my guess)
},
render: function(data, msg , msg2){
   //msg gives me an object;
   //msg2 gives undefined;
}
```

When I try to call: `self.publishEvent("render",msg,msg2)`, it does return an object, but when I go inside the `render()`, it shows, `msg2` as "undefined", but shows `msg` with some data object. How to I call the `render()`, so that when I access it, it should have both `msg` and `msg2` showing as some objects..

Or should it be this way:

```
self.publishEvent("render",msg);
self.publishEvent("render",msg2);
```

any clue??
Thanks!

Comment: don't you mean var self = this;

Comment: yes, sorry typo, my bad..:(

Comment: not answering because I haven't tested... but I believe the render:function will receive a posted event object as the param, with the msg and msg2 attached to the event, unless publishEvent is a more complex function in a framework you're using.